# Magento 2.3 How to get all the Multi Source Inventory (MSI) locations collection in custom module?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, magento2.3, multi-source-inventory

I want to get all the location names from the **Multi Source Inventory (MSI)**. How could I get a collection of all locations in my custom module?

Here I want to create a new multi-select product attribute name "place", which has the values of all source names as its attribute values.

i.e. if there are 3 sources "**US**, **UK**, **IN**" then attribute has the same values "**US**, **UK**, **IN**" in product form.

> How could I achieve this functionality? Do anyone have an idea about
>   it?

I have attribute script as below:

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $eavSetup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY, 'place',
        [
            'group' => 'General',
            'sort_order' => 30,
            'type' => 'text',
            'backend' => '\Module\Name\Model\Backend\Place',
            'frontend' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'label' => 'Place',
            'input' => 'multiselect',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => true,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => '',
            'searchable' => true,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false
        ]
    );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get the list of sources, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/get-all-sources-list-msi-magento-2/

Comment: Check This: https://mageprince.com/blog/how-to-get-all-list-of-sources-multi-source-inventory-msi-programmatically-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 3):

Try this, it's working for me.

```
global $objectManager;        

$sourceList = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\Source\Collection');
$sourceListArr = $sourceList->load();
$i=1;

$sourceList = array();
foreach ($sourceListArr as $sourceItemName) {
    $sourceCode = $sourceItemName->getSourceCode();
    $sourceName = $sourceItemName->getName();

    $sourceList['sourcecount'] = $i;
    $sourceList['sourceCode'] = $sourceCode;
    $sourceList['sourceName'] = $sourceName;

    $sourceAllList[] = $sourceList;

    $i++;
}

print_r($sourceAllList);
```

//Output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sourcecount] => 1
            [sourceCode] => default
            [sourceName] => Default Source
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sourcecount] => 2
            [sourceCode] => CAN
            [sourceName] => Canada
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sourcecount] => 3
            [sourceCode] => USA
            [sourceName] => United State
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code. It worked for me.

```
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface;

/**
* @var SourceRepositoryInterface
*/
private $sourceRepository;

/**
* @var SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory
*/
private $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;

/**
* Place constructor.
*
* @param SourceRepositoryInterface $sourceRepository
* @param SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory
*/
public function __construct(
  SourceRepositoryInterface $sourceRepository,
  SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory
) {
  $this->sourceRepository = $sourceRepository;
  $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory = $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
}

/**
* {@inheritdoc}
* @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
public function getAllOptions()
{
  if (!$this->_options) {
      /** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */
      $searchCriteriaBuilder = $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory->create();
      $searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
      $sources = $this->sourceRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
      foreach ($sources as $source) {
          $this->_options[] = [
            'value' => $source->getCountryId(),
            'label' => $source->getCountryId()
          ];
      }
  }
  return $this->_options;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following way. Guess **SR\MagentoStackExchange\Model\Backend\Place** is your backend.

```
<?php
namespace SR\MagentoStackExchange\Model\Backend;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend;
use Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class Place extends AbstractBackend
{
    /**
     * @var SourceRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $sourceRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;

    /**
     * @var RequestInterface
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * Place constructor.
     *
     * @param SourceRepositoryInterface $sourceRepository
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        SourceRepositoryInterface $sourceRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilderFactory $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory,
        RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->sourceRepository = $sourceRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory = $searchCriteriaBuilderFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $object
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $sources = $this->request->getParam('sources', []);
        $assignedSources = $sources['assigned_sources'] ?? [];

        if (count($assignedSources) > 0) {
            $sourceCodes = [];
            foreach ($assignedSources as $assignedSource) {
                $sourceCodes[] = $assignedSource['source_code'];
            }

            if (count($sourceCodes) > 0) {
                /** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder */
                $searchCriteriaBuilder = $this->searchCriteriaBuilderFactory->create();
                $searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('source_code', $sourceCodes, 'in')->create();
                $sources = $this->sourceRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
                $countries = [];
                foreach ($sources as $source) {
                    $countries[] =  $source->getCountryId();
                }

                $countries = array_unique($countries);
                $object->setData('place', implode(',', $countries));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help  @Sohel Rana. But my question is if I use this code then each time of product save it will get source id different for each product place attribute,
How can I solve that? The answer is helpful but needs some more clarification.

Comment: Without attribute, option id it is not working. it saves data in the database but filter is not working on the frontend.

Comment: Why are you looking option id when you save dynamic data?

Comment: filter is not wokring on frontend

Comment: in table "catalog_product_entity_text" entry is there but no entry in  "eav_attribute_option_value" thats why it is not working i think.

Comment: In that case, you need to create options of your attribute, then need some modification in Place class. Modification $object->setData('place', implode(',', $countries)); line. Need here to assign option id. So fetch option id using Option Text.

Comment: how can we use with product collection of layer navigation ?